# RaspberryPi 3 B+: Error in running two webcams simultaneously

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, webcam

I purchased two webcams ([Logitech C310 HD Webcam](https://www.amazon.in/Logitech-C310-HD-Webcam-Black/dp/B008QS9KMW)) to use with RaspberryPi (RPi 3 B+ model). When I run individual cameras, they are running fine but when I tried to run both cameras at the same time it didn't run. I came to know that it may be due to less power in Raspberry Pi, so I purchased a powered USB hub ([Power USB hub](https://www.amazon.in/Segolike-480Mbps-Speed-USB2-0-Adapter/dp/B0711MHVBJ)). When I attached both cameras with raspberry pi through a power USB hub, it shows an error.

```
VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument
    cv2.imshow("frame2",frame2)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.4) /home/pi/packaging/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:356: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

My code is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
from imutils.video import WebcamVideoStream
from imutils.video import VideoStream

cam1 = WebcamVideoStream(src=0).start()
cam2 = WebcamVideoStream(src=2).start()
#cam1 = VideoStream(src=0).start()
#cam2 = VideoStream(src=2).start()

while (1):
 frame1 = cam1.read()
 cv2.imshow("frame1",frame1)
 frame2 = cam2.read()
 cv2.imshow("frame2",frame2)

 k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
 if k == 27:
  break
cam1.release()
cam2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

With single web camera, above code works fine (when this code modifiy for single cam.) 
Why there is an error while trying to run two cameras with Raspberry Pi? How I can run two webcams using Raspberry Pi.

Comment: what happens if you use code for one camera and plug in both cameras?

Comment: In that case, single camera only run. If I used `cam1 = WebcamVideoStream(src=0).start()`, then first cam run and if I used `cam1 = WebcamVideoStream(src=2).start()`, then second cam runs. But, whenever I tried to run both cams, it shows error as mentioned in question.